# Compare length of longest side of quadrilateral with sum of other sides

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, quadrilateral

Discover, state, and prove a theorem that compares the length of the longest side of a quadrilateral with the sum of the lengths of the other three sides.

I attempted by first drawing a diagonal connecting two vertices of the quadrilateral, and attempting to use the triangle inequality theorem to relate the largest side with the sum of the lengths of the others. I end up with the two equations, A + D > E and B + C > E, and after adding them together, I end up with:

A + B + C + D > 2E,

where A is the longest side, B, C, D are the other sides, and E is the diagonal I drew. I don't know where to go from here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730009/sides-of-a-quadrilateral?rq=1 ?

Comment: let $a \leq b \leq c \leq d$ be the side lengths and $e$ that of a diagonal. By $\triangle-$inequality we get $d \leq c+e$ and $e \leq a+b$, thus $d \leq a+b+c$.

Comment: Thank you Anurag.

Comment: Question: What does this have to do with the longest side? Couldn't you find similar inequalities for c <= a + b + d or any other side?